# Oralce: Get segment size and amount of rows

Tags: oracle

I need a way in Oracle to query the size of the segments as well as the amount of rows for all segment types which are a 'Table'.

Is there a way to combine the statement below (which calculates the size) and the 'count' function?

```
SELECT s.segment_type, (s.bytes / 1024 / 1024) mb, s.segment_name, l.*, s.*
FROM dba_segments s, dba_lobs l
where s.segment_name = l.segment_name(+)
and   s.owner='TEST' order by bytes desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Oracle 12c (please always provide your database version info), you can use the new inline functions.

```
with function fRowCount(aOwner in varchar2, aTableName in varchar2) return number
is
    lCount number;
    begin
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || aOwner || '.' || aTableName into lCount;
        return lCount;
    end;
SELECT case when segment_type = 'TABLE' then fRowCount(s.owner, s.segment_name) else null end rowcount,
s.segment_type, (s.bytes / 1024 / 1024) mb, s.segment_name, l.*, s.*
FROM dba_segments s, dba_lobs l
where s.segment_name = l.segment_name(+)
and   s.owner='TEST' order by bytes desc
```

Please be **really really careful** with that. `execute immediate` without the option of proper binding variables and to be executed as a dba is a dangerous combination.

Answer (score 1):

If you have gathered the stats at schema level then information you are seeking for must be present in `dba_tables`.

You can gather the statistics of the schema using the following:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS('TEST');
```

After that, you can use the following query to fetch the desired result:

```
SELECT
    S.SEGMENT_TYPE,
    ( S.BYTES / 1024 / 1024 ) MB,
    DT.NUM_ROWS,
    S.SEGMENT_NAME,
    L.*,
    S.*
FROM
    DBA_SEGMENTS S
    LEFT JOIN DBA_LOBS L ON ( S.SEGMENT_NAME = L.SEGMENT_NAME )
    LEFT JOIN DBA_TABLES DT ON ( S.SEGMENT_NAME = DT.TABLE_NAME )
WHERE
    S.OWNER = 'TEST'
ORDER BY
    BYTES DESC
```

**Note:** Always use standard ANSI joins.

Cheers!!